# Ruby Sequel: Array returned by query is being returned as a String object, not an Array object

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using the [pg_array](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html) extension of Ruby Sequel.

When I select a column that is a Postgresql array, the result is a string in Ruby.  How do I get this to be a Ruby array so I can use things like .each on it?

```
CaseTypeCategory.first(category_name: 'Subscription')[:values]
=> "{value_one,value_two}"

CaseTypeCategory.first(category_name: 'Subscription')[:values][0]
=> "{"
```

Our database config includes:

```
Sequel.extension :pg_array, :pg_inet, :pg_json
```

And the migration to add the columns included this:

```
alter_table :case_type_categories do
  add_column :values, "text[]"
end
```

I can write raw SQL to access single elements in the array:

```
select values[1] from case_type_categories where category_name = 'Subscription'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you configure Sequel to use the pg_array extension for this column.

Comment: @JordanRunning Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DB.extension :pg_array, :pg_inet, :pg_json`, not `Sequel.extension :pg_array, :pg_inet, :pg_json`.  Otherwise you are just requiring the files without modifying the configuration for the Sequel::Database instance.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Just to confirm: `DB = Sequel::Model.db` right?